# How to run multiple downloads at once in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, queue

There is list of functions in a queue where each function downloads a file. Any ideas on how can I initially start 3 concurrent functions at once, and upon the completion of any of those downloads/function finishes, we want to run the next downloads/function in the queue. At a single time there will be 3 downloads/function running at most.

I tried this but this is not giving me the result. I think it's the loop is freezing the screen.

```
    static void startBackgroundProcess(Iterable<dynamic> iterable, Future<bool> Function(Order) function) async {
    Iterable<dynamic> _iterable = iterable;
    int lenght = iterable?.length ?? 0;
    List<dynamic> queue = [];
    int active = 0;
    int curr = 0;
    int upper = 1;
    _iterable.forEach((i) {
      queue.add(i);
    });
    while (queue.isNotEmpty) {
      if (active < 3) {
        active++;
        function(queue[0]).then((x) {
          queue.removeAt(0);
          active--;
        });
        active++;
        function(queue[1]).then((x) {
          queue.removeAt(1);
          active--;
        });
        active++;
        function(queue[2]).then((x) {
          queue.removeAt(2);
          active--;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```